# C recursive function to calculate Factorial

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

Im just beginning to learn C programming and figured i would start out at a pretty basic problem of calculating the factorial of a number. My code outputs the correct value up until the factorial of 13 and then gives me the wrong answer for when the input is >13. My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
long int factorial(int);

int main()

{
    int num;
    long int fact;
    printf("Please type the number you want factoralized: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    fact = factorial(num);
    printf("%d",fact);
    return 0;
}
long int factorial(int dig)
{
    long int facto;
    if (dig>1)
        facto = dig * factorial(dig-1);
    else if (dig=1)
        facto = 1;
    return facto;
}
```

When i input 13 it returns 1932053504 instead of the expected 6227020800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably overflowing the LONG_MAX value on your platform which leads to *undefined behaviour*. You can use *unsigned long* (or *unsigned long long*) but they wouldn't hold for much longer either.

Your options are limited here. You could use libraries, such as [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org/) that support arbitrarily large integers. Otherwise, you'll have to implement it yourself similar to GMP.

On another note,

```
else if (dig=1)
```

is not what you want. It should be

```
else if ( dig == 1 )
```

Or you can simply use `else {...}` here unless you intend to check against negative numbers.

Comment: What would be the difference in using = and == I get why i could use the last part but why is == needed instead of =

Comment: `=` is assignment and `==` is for comparison. If you do `if (dig=1)` it'll assign `1` to `dig` and resulting condition is *true*.