# Why my simple C code to calculate factorial not working

Tags: c, factorial

Following code returns correctly if I enter ZERO or NEGATIVE value. But, if I enter any positive value it does nothing.
Can someone explain why? My expectation is, it should return factorial of positive number.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int functionfact(int);

void main()
{
    int x,fact;

    printf("Input an integer value:\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    if (x<0)
        printf("Please enter positive value!!");

    else if (x==0)
        printf ("The factorial of 0 is 1");

    else
    {
       fact=functionfact(x);
       printf("The factorial of %d is %d",x,fact);
    }
}

int functionfact(int n)
{
    return(n*functionfact(n-1));
}
```

Comment: When does `functionfact` stop?

Comment: there isn't any termination condition for `functionfact` function.

Comment: Hint: for e.g. 5 you're calculating  5*4*3*2*1*0*-1*-2*-3*... etc. You need to stop at 1.

Comment: You can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876765/c-recursive-function-to-calculate-factorial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C recursive function to calculate Factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876765/c-recursive-function-to-calculate-factorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've upvoted Kalbi's proposal, but I would write it as:

```
int functionfact(int n)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        return n * functionfact(n-1);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Let's face it: this question is asked by a beginner who is learning about the basics of recursion. Best is to first give a complete understanding of how to deal with such kind of programming (as we all struggled with it before, recursion is not easy), and only afterwards, let's make some typical C oneliners.

Answer (score 3):

As Eric pointed out, there is no way for the function to now when to stop.

It should work if you just change the function to

```
int functionfact(int n)
{
    return n > 0 ? (n*functionfact(n-1)) : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Dear!**

There is not any termination condition for function functionfact. You can try this...

```
int functionfact(int n)
    {
        if(n>1)
        return(n*functionfact(n-1));
    }
```

I hope u got your answer.